# MQTT, Paho, IMqttAsyncClient, connection retry

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

Advice please on connection management and retries with IMqttAsyncClient in Java

I see that connection options include auto-reconnection, which in the synchronous client only come into play when an initial connection has been made.

I don't see explicit documentation on the behaviour for IMqttAsyncClient is the initial connection fails. Am I required to have retry logic in my code for the initial connection?

So far it appears that when I attempt to connect as expected the failure callback fires. But then what am I supposed to do? Am I required to code some retry logic myself? In the later auto-reconnect scenario, retries occur. At first sight it appears that once the initial connection fails then that's it.

I have coded a retry in the failure callback

```
// my original connection method, re-used below from failure
... connect(... params ...) { 
         attempt connection using MqttAsyncClient.connect()
}
// callback
public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
    // log failure here
    // User Context lets me know what we're trying to do
    if ( "connecting".equals(asyncActionToken.getUserContext()) 
            && ( ! myShutdownRequested ) ) {
        // log retrying and sleep a bit here
        connect(); // calling original connect method again
    }       
}
```

explicit questions

1. Do I have responsibility for handling retries? Seems odd, given the auto-try capability, but so it goes.
2. In which case is it safe to call MqttAsyncClient.connect() from inside the failure callback?

I've failed to find explicit documentation on either point, and "did I try it" doesn't cover point 2. If there's a subtle race condition any problem might not show up immediately. So far it appears to work nicely ...

Comment: Have you tried testing it?

Comment: @hardlib yes, I've added more detail, however my real concern is not "what works" but "what is supposed to work" as I've explained.

Comment: I'll have a proper look later, but you might do better asking on the Paho dev mailing list (that way the doc might get updated as well)

Comment: Good point! SO is just so easy in comparison.

Comment: Did you find answer to your question? I am using rust version that uses mqtt C library binding. I am getting random segmentation fault at the time of failed connection. I think this might be due to retrying connect in a loop.

Comment: @MohammadAzim I'm sorry but I did not find a definitive answer. Pragmatically my code has been working.